# Count on how many tickets are logged this month - per series

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I have two columns - one with ID's in and one with the date it was created on.

Is there a way which will do a count on how many ID's were created in the current month - and will automatically reset itself when it falls into the next month.

E.g.

```
ID  Creation Date
8.88    01/01/2019
8.89    01/01/2019
8.9 01/07/2019
1.1 01/07/2019
1.2 01/06/2019
1.3 01/05/2019
1.4 01/04/2019
5   01/07/2019
5.1 01/07/2019
5.2 01/06/2019
5.3 01/06/2019
```

If i use the current month (July 2019) - i would hope to see - ID which begin with 8, there was 1 created this month. ID'w which begin with 1 - 1 was created this month & ID's which begin with 5 - there were two created this month

Thank you

Comment: Is the dates formatted as dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data starts in `A1` it would come down to:

---

> *"Is there a way which will do a count on how many ID's were created in the current month - and will automatically reset itself when it falls into the next month."*

**To get the total of entered ID's:**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(B2:B12)=MONTH(TODAY())))
```

You could also use a `COUNTIFS` formula like so:

```
=COUNTIFS(B2:B12,">="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,B2:B12,"<="&EOMONTH(TODAY(),0))
```

---

> *"Is there a way that it can be broken down into each ID. E,g, Taking the LEFT 1st number - e.g. Just reference against the 5 series numbers and returning the results."*

**To get the total of unique series numbers entered:**

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF(MONTH(B2:B12)=MONTH(TODAY()),MATCH(LEFT(A2:A12,1),LEFT(A2:A12,1),0)),ROW(A2:A12)-1)>0))
```

Entered as array formula through <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: =SUMPRODUCT(--(MONTH(B2:B12)=MONTH(TODAY()))) - That is perfect for the total (Thank you) - Is there a way that it can be broken down into each ID. E,g, Taking the LEFT 1st number - e.g. Just reference against the 5 series numbers and returning the results - in this case - 2

Comment: @kirstysmith589, right I didn't catch that at first, excuse me. Will update the answer in a little bit. Would there always be just 1 ID character?

Comment: Yes - The ID numbers will only ever begin with 1- 9. Thank you!

Comment: @kirstysmith589, right, I updated the answer. You expected to see 2, but there are in fact three series numbers entered this month. :)

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are true dates then you can make a pivot table.

First we need to split the ID data on the "dot".
Insert a new column between ID and creation date.
Select the ID column and click Data -> text to columns.

[image]

Split the column on `.`.
The new column (B) needs to have a header. Just write whatever you want as header.

Go to insert -> pivot table

[image]

Then just drag creation date to Rows field (the months will be added automatically) then and ID to also to Rows field.
Then drag ID to the values field.

[image]

EDIT. I see now that my image shows the dates also. You can remove that from the rows field by just dragging it up again to the list.
[image]